# Is it a good idea to mix Moustache/Handlebars Templating with HAML?

Tags: javascript, haml, template-engine, mustache, handlebars.js

I would like to know if it's a good idea to mix Moustache or Handlebars templating with HAML. If yes, what would be the benefits and disadvantages. Why I am asking this? I have seen brogrammers mixing templating. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am generating mustache templates with HAML without any problems.

My HAML looks kinda like this:

```
.template.shop
  .foreground
    .header
      .header-logo
    .shop-description
      .table-frame
        %a.close-button{:href=>"#"} Close
        %table
          %tr
            %td.shop-images
            %td.shop-details
              %p.popup-headline.fix-width
                {{addr_name}}
              %p
                {{addr_street}} {{addr_number}}
                %br/
                {{addr_zip}} {{addr_city}}
              / {{#hasSchedule}}
              %p.popup-headline
                \&Ouml;ffnungszeiten
              %table.shop-schedule
                / {{#sched_mo}}
                %tr
                  %td Mo:
                  %td {{sched_mo}}
                / {{/sched_mo}}

                ... Rest of Table omitted
```

This works like a charm. It gets rendered as HTML on the server which I extract from the page using jQuery on the client. I then take the HTML of the template and render it using mustache.

Because of this, you sometimes need to be **careful where the mustache tags occur**. For the browser they're just text so they're invalid between table rows for example. In this case put them in HTML-comments like in my example.

You could also escape the generated HTML/Mustache on the server. That wasn't feasible in my case because I *wanted* to have the generated template part of my HTML for easier styling.

Comment: I think if you put the generated code in a script tag with a type that the browser can not recognize, for example type="text/x-handlebars-template", the browser will not mess with the "invalid" HTML (tags that are between table rows for example), so you would not have to worry about putting them in HTML-comments

Comment: Yes, that would also work. You could also (on the server ) render into a string and put that string into Javascript somewhere. In my case I explicitly wanted/needed this to be part of the DOM for easier development.

Comment: Actually I don't think that will work, because HAML is clever about not generating invalid HTML.  So if you put them around TRs for instance, it pulls out the text strings and puts them before the table.  I did not know about the comment hack until I found this post, and that works flawlessly, so thank you Jan.